# export 'MdToolbarModule' was not found in '@angular/material'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **`"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11"`** in one of my pet project, and the package.json has the reference as follows,

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11"
```

I have imported the necessary modules as follows,

```
import { MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule, MdGridListModule, MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [        
 ],
 imports: [
 MdToolbarModule,
 MdIconModule,
 MdGridListModule,
 MdButtonModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

but it throws an error export **`'MdToolbarModule' was not found in '@angular/material'`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not MdToolbarModule anymore.
Now it is called

```
MatToolbarModule
```

So the import should be

```
import { MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: I am aware of that :) ,such a silly mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah. pressure makes us forget everything for a moment. But instead scratching head for an hour with small mistakes, it is better to ask and fix it quickly. :)

Comment: haha! its not pressure though! may be i have frequently used old version

Comment: oh yeah. that's true. XD